# Javascript regex that matches one pattern in string but exclude another

Tags: javascript, regex, exec, match

I have two possible strings that I need to match:

+/-90000

and

+9000 / -80000

I need to recognise the two patterns separately so wrote some regex for this.  The first single number string I can match like so:

```
/\+\/\-{1}/g
```

And i wrote this for the second:

```
/(\+(?=[0-9]+){1}|\-(?=[0-9]+){1}|\/(?=\s){1})/g
```

The second would also partially match the first the first number i.e. the -90000. Is there a way that they can be improved so that they match exclusively?

Comment: I am trying to match to determine which type of string the user has input into the system.  They are allowed to input either into the same control but I need to perform different validation and work flows for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single expression:

```
^(?:(\+\/-\s*\d+)|((\+\s*\d+)\s*\/\s*(-\s*\d+)))$
```

The only restriction you'll have to work with would be that in the second type of input, the positive number should come first.

You'll get the matched group in `matches[1]` if the input was of type 1, and in `matches[2]` if it was of type 2. For the type-2 input, further matches of each number gets stored in `matches[3]` and `matches[4]`.

You can see the [demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fR5eM4/1).

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions with slightly different semantics.

With the first, if the string is type 1 the number will be in capture group 1 (`result[1]`) and if it's type 2 the numbers will be in capture groups 2 and 3 (and capture group 1 will be `null`). The test for type 1, then, is `result[1] !== null`.

```
var a = '+/-90000';
var b = '+9000 / -80000';
var result;

var expr1 = /\+(?:\/-(\d+)|(\d+) \/ -(\d+))/;
result = a.match(expr1);
// => [ '+/-90000', '90000', null, null ]
result = b.match(expr1);
// => [ '+9000 / -80000', null, '9000', '80000' ]
```

With the second, if the string is type 1 the number will be in capture group 1 (and capture group 2 will be `null`), and if it's type 2 the numbers will be in capture groups 2 and 3. The test for type 1 is `result[1] === null`.

```
var expr2 = /\+(\d+ )?\/ ?-(\d+)/;
result = a.match(expr2);
// => [ '+/-90000', null, '90000' ]
result = b.match(expr2);
// => [ '+9000 / -80000', '9000', '80000' ]
```